# JavaScript merging two multidimensional arrays into unique arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, merge, lodash, unique

I am trying to sort data that looks like this:

```
{
    "Params": [
        ["section", "North"],
        ["monitor", "Single Monitor"],
        ["section", "North"],
        ["monitor", "Dual Monitor"]
    ]
}
```

Into something that looks like this:

```
{
    "section": [
        "North"
    ],
    "monitor": [
        "Single Monitor",
        "Dual Monitor"
    ]
}
```

But I am currently having issues, I've tried a few different things such as concatenating the arrays together in a loop, or even using lodash's uniq function but every time I get a non desired result.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: _"I've tried a few different things..."_ - Please add your most promising approach and we will try to help you with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can aggregate your array of arrays using `array.reduce`:

```js
let obj = {
    "Params": [
        ["section", "North"],
        ["monitor", "Single Monitor"],
        ["section", "North"],
        ["monitor", "Dual Monitor"]
    ]
}

let result = obj.Params.reduce((acc,cur) => {
   let [key,value] = cur;
   if(!acc[key]){
      acc[key] = [];
   }
   if(!acc[key].includes(value)){
      acc[key].push(value);
   }
   return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: why `find` for a single value? `includes` woud work better.

Answer (score 1):

Number of operation needs to be done here. You can make use of `reduce` in order to group the key wise data. Since you have only key value pair array format, so in reduce I have destructured it with `[k,v]` indicating key and value. Then to remove duplicate values, I have used `Set`.

```js
var data={
    "Params": [
        ["section", "North"],
        ["monitor", "Single Monitor"],
        ["section", "North"],
        ["monitor", "Dual Monitor"]
    ]
};

var result = data.Params.reduce((a,[k, v])=>(a[k] = [...(a[k] || []), v], a[k] = [...new Set(a[k])], a),{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.groupBy()` the `_.head()` (first item of each pair) to group items. Then use `_.mapValues()` to iterate each group, map it to get the `_.last()` item, and the use `_.uniq()` to get just the unique values:

```js
const data = {"Params":[["section","North"],["monitor","Single Monitor"],["section","North"],["monitor","Dual Monitor"]]};

const result = _.mapValues(
  _.groupBy(data.Params, _.head), // group by the first item
  g => _.uniq(_.map(g, _.last)) // map each group to the last item, and get unique values
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

With lodash lodash/fp you can generate a function using `_.flow()` that does the same thing:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, head, mapValues, map, last, uniq } = _;

const fn = flow(
  groupBy(head),
  mapValues(flow(
    map(last),
    uniq
  ))
);

const data = {"Params":[["section","North"],["monitor","Single Monitor"],["section","North"],["monitor","Dual Monitor"]]};

const result = fn(data.Params);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to [groupBy](https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-group-by-array-of-objects-using-a-key/#carbonads:%7E:text=How%20to%20groupBy%20using%20reduce%20in%20Javascript) function as follows

```js
let obj = {
  "Params": [
    ["section", "North"],
    ["monitor", "Single Monitor"],
    ["section", "North"],
    ["monitor", "Dual Monitor"]
  ]
};

const res = obj.Params.reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
  if (!acc[key].includes(val)) {
    acc[key].push(val);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```